# How to access a Named Item that is local to a worksheet

Tags: excel, office-js

To access a globally scoped Named Item I use something like

```
var nm=context.workbook.names.getItem("DynRange").load("name,type,value");
```

in the JS-API the workbook names collection does not contain locally scoped named items for instance Sheet1!LocalName (unlike VBA).
And there does not seem to be a worksheet.names or worksheet.namedItemCollection or anything similar.

So how do I access a named item that is scoped to a worksheet?

Comment: Hi Charles, What about prepending the name with the sheetname? var nm=context.workbook.names.getItem("Sheet1!DynRange").load("name,type,value");

Comment: Tried that - does not work - local names are not contained in the workbook.names collection in JS-land

Comment: And (BTW) Names returning arrays: .Value returns a #Value error, and you can only get the refersto if the name resolves to a range, otherwise a named formula that resolves to a scalar returns the value rather than the formula, and you can't do evaluate yet. And you can't define a name using Range.Name="Fred". Its all a bit weird/buggy.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams, see my answer.  For not being able to define, `range.name = "Fred"`, I would argue that it's by design (name-to-range is 1-to-1, whereas range-to-name can be 1-to-many).  But in the 1.4 APIs, you *will* be able to do `worksheet.names.add("Fred", range)`

Comment: As Michael points out - most of these problems are because I was using API set 1.3 but thinking I was using API set 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locally-scoped named item collections are coming in `ExcelApi 1.4`, which will be publicly available in roughly a month (and available on Insider Fast already, and on Insider Slow soon).  You will want the January fork of the Office 365 subscription (build number 7870+)

(For the different Office versions/flavors, as well as API versioning, I talk about it in the recent update to my e-book, sections "*3.3: Office versions: Office 2016 vs. Office 365 (MSI vs. Click-to-Run); Deferred vs. Current channels; Insider tracks)*" and "*3.4: Office.js API Versioning*".  The book, "Building Office Add-ins using Office.js" is available at https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins/)

Comment: Github says version 1701 for 1.4 - I https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/ExcelJs_1.4_OpenSpec/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets.md - I am currently on 1701 7766.2060. How do I check the API version?

Comment: looks like Github is wrong - 1701.7766.2060 is API 1.3